# Get e-mail Contacts from exchange 2007 in C#

Tags: c#, exchange-server-2007

Is anybody know how to pull contact list from Microsoft Exchange 2007 using c#?

Comment: This would be a better fit on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to do this would be through [Exchange Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Exchange web services is your best bet for this, or you can host a PowerShell runtime in your app and access Exchange that way.